# Copy code to dyno, execute it, get output

Tags: heroku

We have feature-systems for our development branches, and if CI is ok, then the code gets deployed to the matching feature system.

This takes roughly 20 minutes.

Sometimes I would like to speed it up, and execute code without going through CI.

1. copy code to feature-system
2. execute code on the feature-system
3. get the result from the feature-system to my local machine.

The CI use-case is just an example. Above three steps could do something else, too. In the past my servers where accessible via ssh, hence up to now Heroku feels a bit restricted.

How to do these above three steps?

Comment: What is a feature-system if I may ask?

Comment: @abhishek77in in Heroku the feature system is called "App". It contains some dynos. It is a reduced copy of the production system. We use it, so that stakeholders can check changes before they get merged to master.

Comment: Just setup heroku review apps - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration-review-apps it allows skipping CI

Comment: @abhishek77in I am looking for a way to do the above three steps. I think these three steps are not related to CI. In the introduction I talked about CI, but overall it is about these three steps.